# Вывод переменной и спан содержимое html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть переменная:

```
var arr = $('#hidden').val().replace(...);
```

Нужно вставить значение этой переменной и спан в содержимое html:

```
$('.class').html("сюда");
```

Пример того, что **не** должно получиться:

```
$('.resume').html("arr + <span>123</span>");
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно вставить.

Comment: Так а что должно получиться? Вы правильно написали, только **arr +** нужно вынести за первую кавычку: **$('.resume').html(arr + "<span>123</span>");**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Было

```
$('.resume').html("arr + <span>123</span>");
```

Стало

```
$('.resume').html(arr + "<span>123</span>");
```